# Reducing pandas series with multiple nan values to a set gives multiple nan values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, set, nan

I'm expecting to get `set([nan,0,1])` but I get `set([nan, 0.0, nan, 1.0])`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> l= [np.nan,0,1,np.nan]
>>> set(pd.Series(l))
set([nan, 0.0, nan, 1.0])
>>> set(pd.Series(l).tolist())
set([nan, 0.0, nan, 1.0])
>>> set(l)
set([nan, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Are you asking about the unexpected behaviour or just want to achieve your goal using pandas? you can do `set(pd.Series(l).unique().to_list())`, should work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not all nans are identical:

```
In [182]: np.nan is np.nan
Out[182]: True

In [183]: float('nan') is float('nan')
Out[183]: False

In [184]: np.float64('nan') is np.float64('nan')
Out[184]: False
```

Therefore,

```
In [178]: set([np.nan, np.nan])
Out[178]: {nan}

In [179]: set([float('nan'), float('nan')])
Out[179]: {nan, nan}

In [180]: set([np.float64('nan'), np.float64('nan')])
Out[180]: {nan, nan}
```

`l` contains `np.nan`s, which are identical, so

```
In [158]: set(l)
Out[158]: {nan, 0, 1}
```

but `pd.Series(l).tolist()` contains `np.float64('nan')`s which are not identical:

```
In [160]: [type(item) for item in pd.Series(l).tolist()]
Out[160]: [numpy.float64, numpy.float64, numpy.float64, numpy.float64]
```

so set does not treat them as equal:

```
In [157]: set(pd.Series(l).tolist())
Out[157]: {nan, 0.0, nan, 1.0}
```

---

If you have a Pandas Series, use it's `unique` method instead of `set` to find unique values:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(l)
>>> s.unique()
array([ nan,   0.,   1.])
```