# why does python set leave many np.nan?

Tags: python, numpy, set

when I try:

```
set(np.array([1,2,3,3,3]))
```

I get:

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

which makes sense to me.

when I try:

```
set(np.array([1,2,3,3,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]))
```

I get

```
{nan, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, nan, nan}
```

any ideas why?

Comment: Well... their IDs aren't the same.

Comment: On second thought, it seems like the implementation may have changed, `np,nan` at one point would yield the same object but that's changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245862/reducing-pandas-series-with-multiple-nan-values-to-a-set-gives-multiple-nan-valu

Comment: @RajatMishra better dupe, thanks

Comment: Thanks all, missed the dupe