# Unexpected Behavior with Sets and NaN Values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've observed a peculiar behavior while working with sets in Python involving NaN values. Consider the following scenarios:

When creating a set with duplicate NaN values using

```
{np.nan, np.nan}
```

only one value is retained in the set.

Similarly, when constructing a set with duplicate tuples containing NaN values like

```
{(np.nan,), (np.nan,)}
```

only one value is stored in the set.

However, when I create a set with tuples containing NaN values extracted from a Pandas data structure, like

```
{(pd.Series([np.nan])[0],), (pd.Series([np.nan])[0],)}
```

the set contains both values.

Why does this discrepancy occur?
I suspect that is something related to the equality between NaN values. But it is not clear to me why using pandas should change the result

I expected that the behavior would be consistent across these different methods of creating sets, where duplicate NaN values would be treated the same way.

Comment: You really *shouldn't* expect consistent behavior when you try to add something to a set that violates the invariants a set depends on.

Comment: I just edited to put a significantly simpler Pandas example. It seems to be identical, but I'm just mentioning in case it's not. On that note, the tuple seems to be red herring. You can simplify further to `{pd.Series([np.nan])[0], pd.Series([np.nan])[0]}` → `{nan, nan}`

Comment: This isn't specific to Pandas/NumPy. `import math; {math.nan, math.nan}` → `{nan}` while `{float('nan'), float('nan')}` → `{nan, nan}`. But the underlying reason might not be obvious.

Comment: Also on the flip side, if you use `dtype=object`, you only get one. `{pd.Series([np.nan], dtype=object)[0], pd.Series([np.nan], dtype=object)[0]}` → `{nan}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing pandas series with multiple nan values to a set gives multiple nan values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245862/reducing-pandas-series-with-multiple-nan-values-to-a-set-gives-multiple-nan-valu)